# JXTA Configuration

Tags: configuration, p2p, jxta

can someone help to configure JXTA
 ??

[image]

I'm not understanding what type of uri to place as the rendez vous

Comment: that's _at least_ the third time this popup is placed in a question. PLEASE READ THE LINK AT THE TOP AND FOLLOW IT. if you have a specific issue, give more details.

Comment: The link is dead that's why i'm posting this, try it http://jxta-jxse.dev.java.net/confighelp.html

Comment: Ah, _some_ information. do you have specific rendezvous peers or relays you want to connect to?

Comment: i just want to design a simple p2p system between 2 pc, i'm new to JXTA, i'm getting problem on the configuration only

Comment: have you gone through the tutorials at http://jxse.kenai.com/Tutorials/Tutorials.html? What do you mean by "problem"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Noor, you are using an old version of JXTA. The window you see has been completely removed from the code base in [2.7](http://jxse.kenai.com). It is not used in 2.6 too. JXTA is not configured with this window anymore.

About your question, there are two types of URIs: seed and seeding. Seeds are describing 'locations' of peers devices acting as RendezVous or Relays (i.e., 'super' peers). This information is used directly by peers to connect RDV or relays.

Seedings are locations where peers can load information about locations of seed peers. Typically, they point towards an online xml advertisement document. First, these documents are loaded by peers. Then, the extracted content is used by peers to connect to rdv or relay peers.

You can also read the Practical JXTA II document available online at Scribd. For more details about JXTA configuration.